# accessing external site gives "mixed content" error with angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

my server is running over https, but I need to be able to access a resource on an external site (that I have no control over) that is *only* available via http

I've used the user $resource setup

```
        var tableDefintion = $resource('http://www.externalsite.org/xx/info.php',
        {
            param: '@data'
        }
```

but, obviously, when I make a resource request I get the dreaded "Mixed Content" message and it will not load

I have tried adding *$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist* to the angular config function, but that has made no difference, even when set to  **['**']**

This resource is being used from within a service - is there anything else I can do to get round this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this by getting the client (browser) to do this request then there is no way round this ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content)) as it's a security risk. However if you have a server why not proxy the request via your server so you can do the TLS termination yourself?

Comment: oh, dammit - I had a horrible feeling someone was going to say that ... ;)
I'll add it in and see where I get. 
thanks